# How do i change a cookie value in jquery by clicking <a tag> and assign that cookie value to php variable

Tags: php, jquery

jquery code:

```
$("a").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if($.cookie('targetID') === null){              
            $.cookie('targetID',this.id);
            location.reload();  
        }else{
            $.removeCookie('targetID');
            $.cookie('targetID',this.id);
            location.reload();  
        }   
});
```

php code:

```
$targetID = $this->input->cookie('targetID');
```

Comment: Where is the problem! Can you explain!

Comment: ... and inform us, that you re using plugins / frameworks. There is propably https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie plugin used. PHP code looks like Kohana or something similar.

Comment: I have more than 20 of <a> tags with different id. all i need is when everytime i click any of then, it should change the cookie value and assign the clicked <a> id the the cookie. i am not using plugins